# Могу ли я на мобильном использовать АМР страницу, а на на десктопе полноценную страницу?

Tags: css3, html5, amp

Подскажите плиз, у меня есть новостной портал и мне нужно одну из страниц сделать АМР. Собственно вопрос изложен в заголовке - как это работает, я делаю страничку в АМР с минимальным функционалом и она одинаковая как для мобильного, так и для десктопа или же мне нужно делать 2 странички и уже потом определять с какого устройства я захожу? Извините если задал глупый вопрос, но конкретной инфы накопать не смог. Конструктивная критика приветствуется. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать оба варианта. Однако при создании двух версий: для десктопа и для мобильного, ваша работа удваивается. Кроме того повышается возможность дублирования ошибок. Гуглбот имеет лимит для сканирования. Вероятно быстрее будет сканирован и индексирована одна версия, чем две версии. **[Гугл рекомендует использовать только одну версию](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design)**:

> **Преимущества адаптивного дизайна**
>
> Мы рекомендуем использовать
> адаптивный дизайн по причинам, описанным ниже.
>
> Пользователям удобнее делиться вашим контентом, если для него
> используется единый URL. В этом случае алгоритмы Google точнее
> индексируют параметры страницы, а не регистрируют разные ее версии.
> Создание одной адаптивной страницы занимает меньше времени, чем
> создание нескольких вариантов одного содержимого. Снижается
> вероятность типичных ошибок, характерных для мобильных сайтов. Не
> требуется переадресация, что сокращает время загрузки. Кроме того, при
> переадресации с применением агентов пользователя часто возникают
> ошибки, что вряд ли понравится посетителям. Подробнее о возможных
> неполадках читайте здесь. Экономия ресурсов при сканировании сайта
> роботом Googlebot. Агент пользователя Googlebot может просканировать
> страницу с адаптивным дизайном за один раз. В противном случае
> пришлось бы выполнять сканирование всех версий контента. Такое
> повышение эффективности сканирования позволяет Google точнее
> индексировать содержание вашего сайта и отражать его в поиске.

Если вам надо больше функционала, то **[АМП](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/?referrer=ampbyexample.com)** имеет практически все что нужно для хорошего веб-сайта.

В Интернете есть индекс Google для мобильных устройств. Рейтинг результатов поиска для вашего сайта основан на сигналах от мобильной версии. Несколько дней назад Гугл объявил, что все новые веб-сайты будут рассматриваться как мобильные. Поэтому вызывает большое сомнение тот факт, что надо инвестировать ваше время и усилия для создания двух версий олного веб-сайта. Я не рекомендую вам делать это.

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Адаптивная верстка. Можно было бы на этом закончить, но... В общем все, что не нужно показывать на мобильном - скрываете через @media в css.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!